# Can I turn a 2D image into something like a ribbon without 3D Tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I have a picture that's very long and not very tall. I want to create a graphic like the one below, but with my picture as the "texture".

Can Photoshop do something like that? I'd like to avoid to spin up a 3D Program because then I need to render it, get the image out of it and into Photoshop. They seem to have added 3D Functionality into CS5, I just never looked at it.

Obvious question after that: What would the backside look like?
Are there other applications that can do something like that in a simple way?

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Blender for that.  Make a mesh like the film and map the image as a UV-mapped texture.  Simple for an experienced Blender user - but Blender has a long steep learning curve for anyone with no experience with it.  (But a fun learning curve to climb!)  You can map another image for the backside or set it to any surface texture you like.

Most 2D apps like Photoshop, GIMP, etc aren't going to be able to do that, despite having features and plugins for some neat 3D effects.  It's not impossible for a 2D paint or drawing app plugin to do, but it would need something like a miniature 3D modeling and texturing engine built in.  So might as well use the real thing and have more control over how the filmstrip coils, placement of the image and lighting.